# .net core benchmark library

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

Im trying to use benchmark library and see the result in my docker container log and here is a simple configuration that i've made:

my api:

```
    [MemoryDiagnoser]
    [Orderer(SummaryOrderPolicy.FastestToSlowest)]
    [Authorize]
    public class TrucksController : BaseApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Benchmark]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TruckGridViewSearchResult>> GetTrucks([FromBody] TruckGridViewSearchFilter filters)
        {
           my code ...
        }
}
```

and my program.cs

```
 BenchmarkRunner.Run<TrucksController>();
```

when i want to see the result i get this error:

`Benchmark method GetTrucks has incorrect signature.`

if there is any repo or sample code please refere here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe BenchMarkDotNet supports testing WebApis this way, but I did find an article with a write-up on how to use it to [measure calling a web api](https://www.codemag.com/Article/2209061/Benchmarking-.NET-6-Applications-Using-BenchmarkDotNet-A-Deep-Dive#benchmarking-aspnet-6-applications)

Comment: Thanks for the link but why u don't believe, does it have Any reason? Please let me know

Comment: It's mentioned in the above link. I was also able to find it called out in their docs: [How to run your benchmarks](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/guides/how-to-run.html)